# Why my custom fonts are being overwritten on iOS?

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to use custom fonts in my application. I followed the [instructions](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?Custom%20Fonts%20in%20Smart%20Devices%20Applications,) and everything worked as expected.

The problem is that if I run the application again in Genexus, the custom fonts settings in the xcode's project are overwritten (Android still works).

I tried copy the project from Mac to models folder ("\mobile\iOS\"), but the problem persists.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the instructions:

> As this is donde on the XCode project generated with GeneXus steps 3-5 have to be repeated after each execution from GeneXus.

However, there are a few things you can do to automate the process:

1. Add the fonts to your knowledge base as files, edit the properties for each of the files, set "Extract" to "Always", and in the "Extract to path" property add the relative path to the generated project's folder. Something like "..\mobile\iOS\main_object_name\iOS\Genexus"
2. Edit the template file located at "genexus_install_directory\iOS\Templates\iOS_Genexus\MainName-Info.plist", add the custom fonts key
3. You may also need to edit the project's template file located at "genexus_install_directory\iOS\Templates\iOS_Genexus\MainName.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj" (not sure about that), to add a reference to the fonts files

The best way to know what to add to the files from steps 2. and 3. is to generate the project in GeneXus, make a copy on the Mac before adding the fonts, add the fonts via Xcode as documented, and compare the resulting files with the originals.

A warning, though: the steps 2. and 3. apply to ALL applications generated with that GeneXus install, so you may want to make a copy or at least backup the modified files first.

Comment: The step 1 was not required since the font files are in the Mac.
The step 2 was exactly what you suggested.
And then, the step 3 I added the font's key in the following sections:

/* Begin PBXBuildFile section */

/* Begin PBXFileReference section */

402AFD24134A6CD100466F6A /* GXResources */

1D60588D0D05DD3D006BFB54 /* Resources */

I think it would pretty nice if GeneXus offer some support to custom fonts in a future version to avoid this kind of trouble.

Thank you again.